# Automatic tabular cell switching

Tags: tables, counters, automation

Now I want to automatically switch cols and rows by counting. I have already pinned the issue down to the alignment character `&`:

```
\newcounter{myRow}
\newcounter{myCol}[myRow]
\setcounter{myRow}{1}
\setcounter{myCol}{1}

\newcommand{\testcell}{%
  \fbox{\themyRow, \themyCol}%
  \ifnum\value{myCol}<3%
    &%
  \else%
    \refstepcounter{myRow}%
    \tabularnewline%
  \fi%
  \refstepcounter{myCol}%
}

\newcommand{\testcelltwo}{%
  \fbox{\themyRow, \themyCol}%
  \ifnum\value{myCol}<3%
%     &% (This is the only difference to \testcell)
  \else%
    \refstepcounter{myRow}%
    \tabularnewline%
  \fi%
  \refstepcounter{myCol}%
}

\begin{document}%
  % This raises "incomplete ifnum" errors and looks broken
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \testcell \testcell \testcell \testcell \testcell \testcell
  \end{tabular} \par
  % This works fine
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \testcelltwo & \testcelltwo & \testcelltwo \testcelltwo & \testcelltwo & \testcelltwo
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How to fix that? The usual sources only try to teach me how to use the tabular environment correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to issue `&` or `\tabularnewline` when the conditional has already ended; the usual trick is to use `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{myRow}
\newcounter{myCol}[myRow]
\setcounter{myRow}{1}
\setcounter{myCol}{1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\testcell}{%
  \fbox{\themyRow, \themyCol}%
  \ifnum\value{myCol}<3
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {&\refstepcounter{myCol}}%
  {\refstepcounter{myRow}\tabularnewline\refstepcounter{myCol}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\testcell \testcell \testcell \testcell \testcell \testcell
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: one of the `%` in the definition of `\testcell` is redundant. Exercise: which one?

---

Some notes about the trick. If the conditional is true, then `\ifnum` and the tokens necessary for the comparison are removed, leaving

```
\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
{&\refstepcounter{myCol}}{\refstepcounter{myRow}\tabularnewline\refstepcounter{myCol}}
```

in the input stream. Now `\expandafter` expands `\else`, whose expansion is empty after gobbling everything up to and including the matching `\fi`, leaving

```
\@firstoftwo{&\refstepcounter{myCol}}{\refstepcounter{myRow}\tabularnewline\refstepcounter{myCol}}
```

which then becomes

```
&\refstepcounter{myCol}
```

In case the conditional is false, the tokens for the comparison are removed, but together with everything up to and including `\else`, so in the input stream we have

```
\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
{&\refstepcounter{myCol}}{\refstepcounter{myRow}\tabularnewline\refstepcounter{myCol}}
```

Now `\expandafter` expands `\fi`, whose expansion is empty, leaving

```
\@secondoftwo{&\refstepcounter{myCol}}{\refstepcounter{myRow}\tabularnewline\refstepcounter{myCol}}
```

and then

```
\refstepcounter{myRow}\tabularnewline\refstepcounter{myCol}
```

as desired.

To be honest, there are other redundant `%` in the definition, but only because we are in a `tabular`, so this is not general enough for omitting them. The redundant one is the `%` between the two braced groups following `\fi`, because TeX discards spaces when looking for undelimited arguments.

Comment: I never saw `\@firstoftwo` nor `\@secondoftwo` before. To be sure to have gotten it right: expandafter defers expansion of these to when the token after them was fully expanded. The token after them is not `\fi` nor `\else` but the groups either with & resp. tabularnewline inside. So first the conditional is expanded to either `\expandafter\@firstoftwo` or `\expandafter\@secondoftwo`, then the groups are attached and the `\@...` macro finally chooses the group to put. This renders the `%` between the groups redundant as it is never chosen over them.

Comment: @LDericher Not really. The trick has been explained elsewhere, but I'll add some words about it.

Comment: I still try to read TeX like an imperative paradigm, where an "input stream of instructions" is rather uncommon. Your explanation is as beautiful as your solution and roughly matches what I intended to say in my previous comment, though I didn't know yet how *exactly* TeX expands a conditional yet. Is this what do you do for a living? Or did you just at some point devour *The Art of Computer Programming*?

Comment: @LDericher The TeXbook, in particular; but also TeX by Topic, The LaTeX companion, several numbers of TUGboat. And of course my own book on LaTeX programming. ;-)

Comment: Although it's not totally redundant: Since it's inside a definition it saves one character token's worth of memory, and @egreg is old enough to recall a time when that was important.